# How do I remove an object from within a function environment in R?

Tags: r, function, environment

How do I remove an object from the current function environment?
I'm trying to achieve this:

```
foo <- function(bar){
    x <- bar
    rm(bar, envir = environment())
    print(c(x, is.null(bar)))
}
```

Because I want the function to be able to handle multiple inputs.
Specifically I'm trying to pass either a dataframe or a vector to the function, and if I'm passing a dataframe I want to set the vector to `NULL` for later error handling.

If you want, you can watch my [DepthPlotter](https://github.com/japhir/DepthPlotter/blob/master/DepthPlotter.R) script, where I want to let the second function check if `depth` is a dataframe, and if so, assign it to `df` in stead and remove `depth` from the environment.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on what you're trying to achieve, but my suspicion is that you'd be happier simply using some simple S3 dispatch.

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't heard about S3 yet, so I looked it up and found [this site](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/S3.html). But I still don't really understand what it's about. What I want to achieve: I can pass either a vector or a dataframe to `depth`, and the function will check the validity of the arguments and then do with it what I want. Right now I pass `depth` as a vector and `df` as a dataframe, but I want to be able to pass `df` as the first argument without needing to type `df = dataframe`. Instead I want the function call to allow both `DepthPlotter(dataframe)` & `Depthplotter(depth, variable)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a very brief sketch of how to set this up using S3 method dispatch.

First, you define your generic:

```
DepthPlotter <- function(depth,...){
    UseMethod("DepthPlotter", depth)
}
```

Then you define methods for specific classes of the argument `depth`. As a very basic example in your case, you might create only two, a `data.frame` method and a `default` method to handle the vector case:

```
DepthPlotter.default <- function(depth, variable, ...){
    #Here you write a function assuming that depth is
    # anything but a data frame
}

DepthPlotter.data.frame <- function(depth,...){
    #Here you'd write a function that assumes
    # that depth is a data frame
}
```

And then you can call `DepthPlotter()` using either type of argument and the correct function will be run based upon the result of `class(depth)`.

The example I've sketched out here is a little crude, since I've used a default method to handle the vector case. You could write `.numeric` and `.integer` methods to handle numeric or integer vectors more specifically. In my example, the `.default` method will be called for *any* case other than `data.frame`, so if you go this route you'd want to write some code in there that checks for strange cases like `depth` being a complicated list, or other odd object, if you think there's a chance something like that might be passed to the function.

Comment: Thansk a lot! Yesterday I tried implementing your tips, and it worked like a charm! Very convenient and easily extendible if I later want to add, for example, handling of factor data. Still struggling with some duplicate names etc. but getting there. [Here](https://github.com/japhir/DepthPlotter/blob/S3-method-dispatch/DepthPlotter.R) is the script with the working build of your suggestions :).

Is there a way of doing this for multiple variables? So I can check both `var` and `depth` for their class and make the function respond appropriately?

Comment: @Japhir What you're describing is called multiple dispatch. S3 only does single dispatch, but luckily for you R has more object systems than you can shake a stick at. If you really need something like that, you can look at the [S4](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/S4.html) object system.

Comment: `>mind.status == "blown"` 
`>TRUE`. 
hehe, thanks :).
I think I may have to simplify my functions to do fewer things to prevent me from making things too complicated ;).

Comment: Would you say defining .default with a warning and making working versions for .dataframe, .integer and .factor would be nice style?